# How do I integrate the environments of QGIS and Anaconda/Spyder?

Tags: qgis, jupyter-notebook, environment-variable, spyder

I have version 3.34 installed on my Windows 11 desktop. In addition I have a full install of Anaconda which gives me full access to Spyder and JupyterLab, both of which I very much enjoy.

My challenge is to integrate these two environments such that I can go into Spyder or JupyterLab, build code there, test it, execute it and see the results directly in an active session of QGIS.  In terms of preferences I do not want to use the python built into QGIS since the Spyder/JupyterLab environment functions so much more effectively for a developer.

So, to be clear on a needed workflow, I need to:

1. Open QGIS and open an existing project. I want to select an active layer in the interface of QGIS on which to do my coding.
2. I want to then use Spyder/JupyterLab to build, test and execute code using the existing QGIS interface to evaluate whether I succeeded (without ever having closed either one).

What I think this means is that I need access to QGIS libraries from within Spyder/JupyterLab without setting up some complex environment on either side.  I did see something out there where I could setup a virtual environment inside Anaconda but this is not appealing in terms of access to the QGIS interface I may already be using.

Suggestions are most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Surely you will be able to instantiate a Qgis app and project object into Spyder or Jupyter, also load a layer, set it to active and render a map canvas (thanks to Anita Graser for writing [this post](https://anitagraser.com/2023/11/10/bringing-qgis-maps-into-jupyter-notebooks/)). And probably yes, you will need to install QGIS into the same conda environment.

But if you need the interface of QGIS as it is open by a regular user, and since suggestions are welcome, I wrote a plugin to run Python code inside QGIS. It is called [puentes](https://github.com/caprieldeluca/puentes).

Just configure it to the file to be run. Then, with a toolbar button or keyboard shortcut (doesn't come preconfigured to avoid collisions) you can run the file within QGIS.

From there, edit the file where you want, just save it, change the focus to the QGIS window and run again.

It is also simple to load a package with utilities, as in my [mochila](https://github.com/caprieldeluca/mochila) project.

I'm sorry this is not the answer you are looking for.  But I also had the need and this was my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Anita Graser (AKA @underdark) wrote an article that I was literally reading today, which may help.

Its a slightly different answer, as she talks about Linux environment and Jupyter notebooks, so its not a complete answer, however it may get you started.
(I am also keen to get this up and running as well, so if I get time to try it out ill update the answer for windows. )

https://anitagraser.com/2023/01/21/pyqgis-jupyter-notebooks-on-windows-using-conda/

She also references another article which was written around deploying using .bat files.

https://lerryws.xyz/posts/PyQGIS-in-Jupyter-Notebook